# Can't Setup "From" field on msmtp

Tags: email, phpmailer

I'm trying to setup msmtp

Here's my config file

```
defaults from name@domainname.co.id

account name 
host 10.1.1.15 
from from name@domainname.co.id
auth off 
port 25

account default : name
```

and here's my log sending email by using php mail() function

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8g7c32atjzsly5j/msmtp-log.txt?dl=0

I can't override the "from" field and it keep using "default"

Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: You need to post actual code. There's nothing to go on here.

Comment: What do you mean by actual code? Just use default mail function. 

php -a 
mail('xxx@gmail.com','test21-13:12','mai contentl');